# Why isn't there any difference between filter scope on those nested subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan, subquery

Given the two sub-queries below, I have been told today that **query (1)** would be inefficient because it **would fetch all data** from the view before filtering them as the where clause is **outside** the nested query.

**(1)** from ORM  *(where outside)*

```
select * from (select * from VW_LOURD) as q  where q.Expr5 = 'SYNC_FLAG'
```

**(2)** from self *(where inside)*

```
select * from (select * from VW_LOURD where Expr5 = 'SYNC_FLAG') as q
```

I rewrote the query as shown on **(2)** in order to have the **filter inside sub-query**. I did not found any noticeable performance differences. To be sure I compared both **execution plan** and they are **exactly the same**.

I came to the conclusion that both queries would fetch similar amount of data and the same way, whether the filter is inside or outside sub-query however, I am not sure if my conclusion is 100% correct, also I am **not able to explain why both queries are similar**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both query are functionaly identical, meaning that they will always produce the same results.

I understand that your intent is to push the filter to the subquery to increase efficientcy. Your database knows better anyway - as a matter of fact, it most likely rewrites both queries as:

```
select * from vw_lourd where expr5 = 'SYNC_FLAG'
```

... which is what they actually are, really. As a consequence, both execution plans are identical.